# Exception on CcTray

Tags: cctray

I am getting below exception on Double clicking Tests/Build on CCTray, I am able to Force Build/Start-Stop Project but on Display Web Page I get exception. I have tried re-installing CCTray but nothing worked.

Exception:

```
Unhandled exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No application is associated with the specified file for this operation
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
       at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.CCTrayLib.Presentation.MainFormController.DisplayWebPageForProject(ISingleProjectDetail project)
       at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.CCTrayLib.Presentation.MainForm.lvProjects_DoubleClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Can anyone help me out to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Change in Brower Version could cause this.
HTML File Association is missing here. You can fix it in Set Default Programs. Steps will be

•   Go to Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Default Programs
•   Select Browser (e.g. Internet Explorer)
•   Choose default programs for this program 
•   Select HTTP and save.

now any HTTP will be open in selected browser.